# OleDb scheme for excel workbook not showing rows in schema

Tags: oledb

I am trying to open an Excel workbook and read from a sheet. Pretty simple.

```
            string sConnction = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"C:\\Users\\sstowe\\Documents\\Ranorex\\RanorexStudio Projects\\BottomLineII\\BottomLineII\\Widget.xls\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO\";";
        string sSql = "Select * FROM Corporate";

        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(sConnction);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sSql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        // var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Get all Sheets in Excel File
        var dtSheet = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

You see var reader... commented out as I examine. I received an error "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Corporate'.  where Corporate is the name of the sheet. Gee says I, did I make a mistake with the name or something? So I opened dtSheet to look. In the debugger, dtSheet is reporting 0 rows yet cn is reporting State of Open. So the workbook is being found. Can someone advise as to how to find the sheet?

Thank you.

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet names always have a $ at the end and you chould bracket it so change your SQL to...

```
Select * From [Corporate$]
```

Sheet names with spaces are bounded by single quotes so a sheet called "Corporate Data" would be...

```
Select * From ['Corporate Data$']
```

You can have a look at the available sheets with...

```
DataTable dtTablesList = new DataTable();
dtTablesList = cn.GetSchema("Tables");
```

Comment: Bingo. Must be the front row. Thank you.